# Rebuild fails after adding reference in Unit Test App Nunit Lite Xamarin to Xamarin Service

Tags: android, xamarin, nunit

I have android xamarin app project that I want test. (Xamarin application, bound service)
I have created Unit Test App project.(nunit lite) I have added reference to project I want test via visual studio in Unit Test App project. When I rebuild solution I get this error. It is caused by adding this reference.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: 
Could not resolve reference to 'System.Void 
System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehaviorAttribute::.ctor()' (defined in 
assembly 'AndroidClientApi, Version=0.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=c45bde296bb8c671') with scope 'System.ServiceModel, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. 
When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually 
means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: 
Failed to resolve System.Void 
System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehaviorAttribute::.ctor()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference 
reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkCustomAttribute(CustomAttribute ca)
at 

Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkCustomAttributes(ICustomAttributeProvider 
provider)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition 
assembly)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()    Test
```

Any ideas how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was:

NameOfTheProject -> Properties -> AndroidOptions -> Linking: None

[image]